# How replace a given character by a new line in a xslt transformation?

Tags: xml, replace, xslt-1.0

I'm currently working on an XSLT file to transform an XML file into an HTML file.

In my XML, I retrieve data as

```
    <ns0:Key>
        <ns0:Field>Comments</ns0:Field>
        <ns0:Value>line 1 ¤ line 2 ¤ etcaetera</ns0:Value>
    </ns0:Key>
```

And I want to replace the '¤' by a new line in my transformed HTML page.

I try with this template

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:param name="string" />
            <xsl:param name="replace" />

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($string, $replace)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $replace)" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                <!--<xsl:text><br/></xsl:text>-->
                    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$replace)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>
```

And I applied it as this:

```
<xsl:variable name="string-mod">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="./*[local-name()='Key'][*[local-name()='Field']='Comments']/*[local-name()='Value']" />                                
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#164;'" />        
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I made some tries (I let one in comment in the template) with differents characters and markups but for now nothing worked properly.

If someone has any idea, it would be great :)

Thanks

Please notice that I have to use XSLT 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[RESOLVED]**

Thanks, I figure out a solution this week end.

With this template:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:param name="string" />
            <xsl:param name="replace" />
            <xsl:param name="with" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($string, $replace)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $replace)" />
                    <br/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$replace)" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

Called as this:

```
 <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="./*[local-name()='Key'][*[local-name()='Field']='Comments']/*[local-name()='Value']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&#164;'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

A newline character in an HTML document does not cause text to be displayed on a new line in the browser. The browser collapses all sequences of whitespace characters (including newline) into a single space. To display text on a new line, you need to use a `<br>` tag or similar.

So inserting newline characters into your text has no effect. You need to insert markup.